Suppose that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f '(x) = 0$. Using Mean Value Theorem, show that the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} f (x) / x = 0$ exists and equals $0$.
Been stuck on this problem for a few days now. It is also given that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$, and $f'(x)$ can be finite or infinite. My best attempt now is the following, although I'm not 100% convinced:
By MVT, $\exists c_x\in (a,x)$, where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(a)\in\mathbb{R}$ is finite, s.t. $f'(c_x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$.
Now, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(c_x) = 0$, since we're given that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$ (this is the part I'm uncertain about. Can we make this claim?)
Then $0 = \lim_{x\to\infty}f'(c_x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x-a} - \frac{f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$
So $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$.
Does this proof work? Can we just state that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(c_x) = 0$?

how can you conclude that $c_x\rightarrow\infty$? After all, $c_x$ could be close to $a$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

This question is a (multi)duplicate: If the derivative tends to $0$ at infinity, then so does the function divided by $x$. Found using Approach$0$: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7Df%27(x)%3D0%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bf(x)%7Dx%3D0%24&p=1

That's what I was uncertain about. I was thinking that as $x\to\infty, c_x$ would need to get closer to $x$, since $f'(x)$ approaches 0, meaning $\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$ would also approach 0, since f(x) - f(a) will be increasing at a slower rate than x-a. I'm unsure how to articulate this though without assuming that $f(x)/x$ approaches 0.
